# Active Record Associations - Error w has_many :through Association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_positions
  has_many :job_titles, through: :user_positions

class JobTitle < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_positions
  has_many :users, through: :user_positions

class UserPosition < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :job_title
```

Given the above model ActiveRecord associations, I'm trying to query for a JobTitle and then return all users with that JobTitle like so:

```
JobTitle.where(id: 6).users
```

This is erroring with:

```
undefined method `users' for #<JobTitle::ActiveRecord_Relation
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `where` will give you an ActiveRecordRelationship, many objects, `find` will give you a single one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `find_by` of `find` (`find` raises `RecordNotFound` if there is no record with this id):

```
JobTitle.find_by(id: 6).users
```

It's just how `has_many` works: one model has many other models. `Where` returns a relation, e.g. `JobTitle.where('id > ?', 1)` will return a collection of records. In your case `where` returns a relation with one record, like an array with one element.

Answer (score 1):

The codes **JobTitle.where(id: 6)** return a collection of records, The best way is use the **find** method.

Just try this:

```
 JobTitle.find(6).users
```

Or

```
JobTitle.where(id: 6).first.users
```